# Select each item found by a jquery selector independently, run a function on them 'on load,' so to speak

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the width of an item to the next sibling with a certain class. I have it working, but it sets all instances to match the width of the first instances desired sibling. I think I need to run a function so I can use the $(this) selector to specify this one next sibling, but can't figure out the appropriate jquery event. Have tried on(), read(), and onload().

Jquery

```
$(".table-title").css("width", $(".table-title").next(".data-table").width() - 1);
$(".table-footer").css("width", $(".table-title").next(".data-table").width() - 1);
```

HTML

```
<div class="table-container">
    <h3 class="table-title">Data Table</h3>
    <table class="data-table">
      <tr class="data-table-row">
        <th class="data-table-header">ID</th>
        <th class="data-table-header">Username</th>
        <th class="data-table-header">Email</th>
        <th class="data-table-header">Password</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="data-table-row">
        <td class="data-table-cell">1</td>
        <td class="data-table-cell">Derp</td>
        <td class="data-table-cell">herp@derp.net</td>
        <td class="data-table-cell">123</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="data-table-row">
        <td class="data-table-cell">2</td>
        <td class="data-table-cell">Foo</td>
        <td class="data-table-cell">bar@foo.404</td>
        <td class="data-table-cell">lolz</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="table-footer">
      Table footer
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a function as a parameter which will be invoked for each item in the jQuery collection:

```
$(".table-title").css("width", function() {
    return $(this).next(".data-table").width() - 1);
});
```